# Javascript seems to act weird in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse

I just started to develop some web programs, but I found javascript acting weird in Eclipse.

Normally, all the other codes will be in different color and they'll underline the errors i got, but some of my javascript code doesn't. Is there anything wrong with it.

[image: Image:]

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse is getting tripped up on the fact it's in a .php file - another reason JS and PHP should be kept 100% completely separate

Comment: What is the problem with the screenshot? It does seem to be highlighting your JavaScript code?

Comment: Hey treyBake, I tried creating a .js file and then I wrote <script></script> in it. But, it gives me a missing semicolon error.